# Google Maps API- Formatted phone number shows up as undefined in List on side bar

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a list of the places and their phone numbers on the ride side bar.  the phone numbers work when i click on the markers but show up as undefined in the side bar.  any help is great thanks.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  

    var map = null;
    var gmarkers = [];
    var service = null;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});

  function initialize() {
    var slo = new google.maps.LatLng(35.2742, -120.6631);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: slo,
      zoom: 11
    });

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    var request = {
      location: slo,
      radius: 30000,
      types: ['hospital']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
if (place.icon) {
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            place.icon, new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
 } else var image = null;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
var request =  {
      reference: place.reference
};

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var contentStr = '<h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address;
        if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
        if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';
        contentStr += '<br>'+place.types+'</p>';
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      } else { 
        var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      }
    });

});
gmarkers.push(marker);
 var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'>"+place.name+"-"+place.formatted_phone_number+"</a><br>";
 document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
    }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatted phone number displayed in the infoWindow is returned in the [placeDetails response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses), which happens when the marker is clicked, it isn't available in the [nearbySearch response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses), which is used to create the sidebar.